# Jenkins Bitbucket Server Integration plugin won't let me add or select credentials

Tags: jenkins-plugins, bitbucket-server

I installed the Bitbucket Server Integration plugin and I'm trying to configure it following the instructions on [the plugin page](https://plugins.jenkins.io/atlassian-bitbucket-server-integration/). When trying to select the `Personal Access Token`, the only option is `- none -`. I tried adding a new one and nothing changes. I've rebooted Jenkins, but the issue persists. There are already a bunch of other plugins with the credential options available--it seems that it's just this one that's not working.

Anyone have any tips on getting this working?

Jenkins: v2.319.3

Bitbutcket Server Integration plugin: v3.3.2